# Is a Wiener process a Gaussian process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

My background in measure theory and stochastic processes is poor. In the literature I have found that a Wiener process can be defined as the integral of a white noise Gaussian process. But does this make a Wiener process a Gaussian process? Could you provide a very simple explanation for the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of different definitions of the Wiener process; the one you gave is actually quite mathematically inconvenient (basically since you have to get everything started in the Fourier domain).

A more convenient one explicitly states that the Wiener process is Gaussian (and in particular specifies its mean function as $m(t)=0$ and its covariance function as $R(s,t)=\min \{ s,t \}$). Another starts from an assumption of independent increments, from which the Gaussian property follows by the central limit theorem.

Comment: Thank you! So a Gaussian process is completely specified by its mean and covariance functions?

Comment: So all finite dimensional distributions are specified by the mean and covariance functions. However, to properly specify the Wiener process you must also postulate that it has continuous paths (or at least a.s. continuous paths).